# Platformer Collision Detection and Resolution in OO Manner

Tags: android, oop, collision-detection, game-engine

Firstly, here's a bit of background:

I am developing a 2D game as a personal project possibly for release on mobile devices. I plan on creating a tile based puzzle/platformer with a lot of visual elements.

I have never produced anything of this scale before and I'm wondering how to stick to good OO principles in a relatively large project.

I would like some advice on how to structure some of my code for different types of collisions with different tile types.

- I have solid tiles which my player object can stand on
- water tiles which still detect collisions but allow the player to swim
- background elements without any collision detection

Should I create a base Tile class with abstract methods so that each tile type can behave differently upon a collision or use different layers for each type?

I am also wondering how to keep the physics logic of my player object together rather than parts in the tile classes and some in the player object class?

As you can see I am quite inexperienced in terms of knowing what works best in certain situations.

Can anyone give me some general guidance in these areas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look into creating a [component entity system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity_component_system) for the entities. Because you've tagged this as for Android, I assume you're using Java. You can also implement this similarly for your tiles, making interfaces for each part of the tile you need. For example, you could make an ISwimmable interface that applies to water and your liquids. You would have an ISolid for solid blocks that you can't walk through. The background elements would not have any components implemented. You would implement these interfaces in classes derived from a single Tile class, with a few minimalistic abstract methods. Try to keep the methods You might even try to create a class where tile types are "registered" so that you can look them up when performing collisions.

For physics, you could find an external physics engine like bullet or box2d. If you want to do the physics yourself you will probably need to keep it separate from collisions with the world. If you want some kind of flying entity you might want it to be able to be stopped by solid tiles, but not affected by gravity, so have a physics component in the component entity system and a collision component. When iterating through your entities, use the collision component to see if the player/enemy/somethingElse is on the ground, and if not, use the physics component to apply acceleration due to gravity (or just move it down at a constant velocity if it has reached terminal velocity). You'll have one big list of entities, instead of a complicated hierarchy of them. This kind of structure is very well used by professionals today.